# How many ways to pick 3 balls from 50 of 5 colors? (nPr nCr)

Tags: combinatorics

Confused with the following counting problem:

> How many ways can I pick $3$ balls from a bag of $50$ balls of $5$ colors ($10$ of each color) using $nCr$ or $nPr$?

So far, my thinking is that I can pick...

All the same color $\binom51$

All different colors $\binom 53$

$2$ same $1$ different $\binom52\binom31$

To account for all these possibilities, I will add the probabilities together to make

$$\binom51+\binom53+\binom52\binom31$$

My question here is, well, first of all am I approaching this the right way? Further, do I need to multiply that sum by $50P3$ because of the number of balls that are available? Alternatively, would it be sufficient to simply solve by $4\cdot\binom{10}1^4$? I doubt this, but then again I have a way of overcomplicating things.

Much appreciated. PS answer must be achieved with nCr or nPr.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: I don't understand the last one.  After choosing $2$ colors from $5$ there are only $3$ left, so the answer should be $\binom52\binom31$  Also, you are treating all balls of the same color as indistinguishable.  I should think the answer expected for the first part, for example, $\binom51 \binom{10}{3}$

Comment: @saulspatz you are correct regarding 3 left, I have edited the question. Is my solution now correct?

Comment: @MathLover semantics noted. What would be an appropriate word instead of "probability"?

Comment: You can choose to say combinations, selections, ways... I just called out probability because it has a completely different meaning here. That is all.

Answer (score 1):

Find number of selections of $3$ balls from a bag of $50$ balls of $5$ colors ($10$ of each color). Considering balls of the same color identical,

We need all possible combinations of $3$ balls from balls of $5$ different colors. Using stars and bars method, your answer is simply

$\displaystyle {3 + 5 - 1 \choose 5 - 1} = {7 \choose 4} = 35$

The way you did, it would be $\displaystyle \binom51+ 2 \, \binom52 + \binom53 = 35$